# show entity in second level of array in symfony

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I don't know the exact term for showing the entity in second level of array.
I have entity Doctor. see my list in my image

[image]

If you can see the entity Person under the Doctor list. It display the Person entity like firstName and lastName. How can I show the same in facilityPackageDoctors? I expect it shows the package name and the facility, and what it displays now is not the list of facilityPackageDoctors. Here is my query

```
public function getFacilityPackageDoctors($facilityId){    
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->leftJoin('d.facilityPackageDoctors', 'fpd')
            ->leftJoin('fpd.facilityPackage', 'fp')
            ->where('fp.facility = :parameter')
            ->setParameter('parameter', $facilityId)
            ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Do I have something to setup on this? sorry for the term I used.

Comment: `->select('fp')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like that

```
public function getFacilityPackageDoctors($facilityId){    
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->leftJoin('d.facilityPackageDoctors', 'fpd')
        ->leftJoin('fpd.facilityPackage', 'fp')
        ->addSelect('fp as facility')
        ->where('fp.facility = :parameter')
        ->setParameter('parameter', $facilityId)
        ->getQuery();
return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: it causes an error [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT fp FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

Comment: Try `addSelect` so you're not overwriting the implicit select of `createQueryBuilder('d')`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to ccKep. I found the solution by adding `addSelect()`

```
public function getFacilityPackageDoctors($facilityId){

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->leftJoin('d.facilityPackageDoctors', 'fpd')
            ->leftJoin('fpd.facilityPackage', 'fp')
            ->addSelect('fpd')
            ->where('fp.facility = :facilityId')
            ->setParameter('facilityId', $facilityId)
            ->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```